# How to get data from a text file in C#

Tags: c#

I have a text file with this info:

```
#ID maxSize tax
1 57247 0.0887
2 98732 0.1856
3 134928 0.2307
4 77275 0.1522
5 29240 0.0532
6 15440 0.0250
7 70820 0.1409
8 139603 0.2541
9 63718 0.1147
10 143807 0.2660
```

I would like to know how to get an `int[]` with the IDs, another `int[]` with the maxSize and a `double[]` with the taxes.

Comment: Hint: use `File.ReadLines` to read the file as lines of text, then write a method to convert each line to an entry. I would strongly advise you *not* to have three separate arrays, but to have a single collection of objects where each object has an Id, MaxSize and Tax property.

Comment: What have you tried? `File.ReadAllLines(filePath);` will return an array representing each line in the file, which you could likely parse into your three columns using `string.Split()`

Comment: How are the values separated on each line?

Comment: @PoulBak with a single space

Comment: Use Split(' ') to split the values, it returns an array of values. Then parse each value in the array into your variables.

Comment: you have to replace dots with comas to be able to parse it into a double. double.parse("0.0887") will return 887 as a double as far as I know.

Comment: only in locales where the dot is the thousands separator. in the invariant culture, the dot *is* the decimal separator.

Comment: Why would you want three separate arrays and not a list containing each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that should do what you want.  Just make sure you change the file name to be the path of your actual file.

It uses `String.Split` to split each line into 3 values. It then parses each of the 3 values into the types you're expecting, and adds them to the various arrays.

```
void ParseData( string data[], out int[] id, out int[] maxsize, out double[] tax )
{
    var lines = data.Select( line => line.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) )
                    .Select( items => Tuple.Create( int.Parse(items[0]), int.Parse(items[1]), double.Parse(items[2]) ) );

    id = lines.Select( s => s.Item1 ).ToArray();
    maxsize = lines.Select( s => s.Item2 ).ToArray();
    tax = lines.Select( s => s.Item3 ).ToArray();
}

int[] ids;
int[] maxsizes;
double[] taxes;
string[] rawdata = File.ReadAllLines(@"FILENAME");

ParseData( rawdata, out ids, out maxsizes, out taxes );
```

Comment: It works similar to the way others have suggested:  It uses String.Split twice:  once to split the file into different lines and again to split each line into 3 values.  It then parses each of the 3 values into the types you're expecting, and adds them to the various arrays.

Comment: I've updated the code to use `ReadAllLines` instead of `ReadAllText` which will split the file into lines, eliminating one of the calls for Split.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a question, is there a way to skip the first line of the text? Because the first line (#ID maxSize tax) doesn-t have numbers.

Comment: @Kuroki if this answer your quesiton, click the gray tick at left side to mark it as answer

Comment: @Kuroki Yes, you can do that.  Change the `ReadAllLines` to read like this:
    `string[] rawdata = File.ReadAllLines(@"FILENAME").Skip(1).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that could read file and parse it to the int[] int[] and double[]

**Note** I am ignoring the first line `#ID     maxSize      tax`
you must include these lines before at the beginning;

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

#### Code

```
var fileName = @"FileName";
var rawLines[] = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
var ids = new List<int>();
var maxSizes = new List<int>();
var taxes = new List<double>();
foreach(var line in rawLines) {
    var data = line.Split(' ');
    ids.Add(Convert.ToInt32(data[0]));
    maxSizes.Add(Convert.ToInt32(data[1]));
    taxes.Add(Convert.ToDouble(data[2]));
}

// using lists
Console.WriteLine($"First Data - {ids[0]}  {maxSizes[0]}  {taxes[0]}");
```

**Note:** If your file consists of first line `#ID     maxSize      tax` then add the following code just after `var data = line.Split(' ');`

```
// safegaurd to prevent exception thrown while converting string to number types
if(!int.TryParse(data[0])) {
     continue;
}
```